# delete IDs with a variable's one value appearing once

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I hope I can explain myself clearly.

I have a dataset like this

```
dataset <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                      Invoice = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), 
                      Invoice_Date = c('09/30/2019','10/30/2019','11/30/2019',
                                       '10/31/2019','11/30/2019','12/31/2019',
                                       '7/31/2019','9/30/2019','12/31/2019'),
                      paid_unpaid = c('no','yes','yes','yes','no','no','no','yes','no'), 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dataset$Invoice_Date <- as.Date(dataset$Invoice_Date, '%m/%d/%y')
```

```
ID. Invoice. Date of Invoice.  paid or not.  
1    1         09/30/2019       no
1    2         10/30/2019       yes
1    3         11/30/2019       yes

2    1         10/31/2019       yes
2    2         11/30/2019       no
2    3         12/31/2019       no

3    1         7/31/2019        no
3    2         9/30/2019        yes
3    3         12/31/2019       no
```

I want to select customers who have more than one unpaid invoices. So the frequency of no in the variable "paid or not" appears more than once.

after selecting, my ideal data looks like this
dataset$Invoice_Date <- as.Date(dataset$Invoice_Date, '%m/%d/%y')

```
    ID. Invoice. Date of Invoice.  paid or not.  

    2    1         10/31/2019       yes
    2    2         11/30/2019       no
    2    3         12/31/2019       no

    3    1         7/31/2019        no
    3    2         9/30/2019        yes
    3    3         12/31/2019       no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(sum(paid_unpaid == 'no') > 1)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID Invoice Invoice_Date paid_unpaid
  <dbl>   <dbl> <date>       <chr>      
1     2       1 2020-10-31   yes        
2     2       2 2020-11-30   no         
3     2       3 2020-12-31   no         
4     3       1 2020-07-31   no         
5     3       2 2020-09-30   yes        
6     3       3 2020-12-31   no
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `subset` with `table` from `base R`

```
subset(dataset,  ID %in% names(which(table(ID, paid_unpaid == 'no')[, 2]> 1)))
#  ID Invoice Invoice_Date paid_unpaid
#4  2       1   2020-10-31         yes
#5  2       2   2020-11-30          no
#6  2       3   2020-12-31          no
#7  3       1   2020-07-31          no
#8  3       2   2020-09-30         yes
#9  3       3   2020-12-31          no
```